# Display filename in file input display

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Basically, what I want to do is get data from the server and display on the update page in my project. So over here, I have an image to display and yes, it displays in the `<div>` to show the image of Taylor Swift. However, I have a problem which I can't find a way to display the file name in the file input itself. (see picture below)

[image]

So expected behaviour would be, the file name gotten from the data from the server, would show in the input itself. E.g. **taylorswift.jpeg**

Is there any way I can do this using javascript? Currently working on a VueJS 2 project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File input field does not allow to select files or set currently selected file name programmatically due to security reasons. But you could create a sort of fake input field using some approaches, on of which is embedding hidden file input field inside a button element as you can see in [this sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzNVzd).

```
<button class="fake-file__input-col">
    <input type="file" class="fake-file__input" @change="onFileInputChange"/>
</button>
```

So when you receive image name from server you can use it to display in your fake input, and when user selects a file with this input, his actual selected file name will be displayed as well.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! Now i have a better understanding. I have customised the sample according to my own project.